# Contacts API Authentification migration - None activity in the Console

Tags: rest, google-oauth, google-contacts-api

We are in the process to migrate our Contacts API from the ClientLogin authentification to the OAuth 2.0 authentification.

We are able to get the Authentification token, to delete or to add contacts in an account.
If the API is disabled in our developer interface or if we are not sending a valid token, we get the corresponding error. So it seems we are connected to the API the right way.

However none of our requests are triggered in the requests activity console for the Contacts API.

Here is what we have in the http header of our requests:

```
User-Agent: ourProductName
Host: www.google.com:443
Authorization: Bearer OurOAuthAccessToken
GData-Version: 3.0
```

What are we doing wrong? How to check if we are using the right track for sending requests to the Contacts API?

Comment: Actually, I think you are doing it right.  I believe that contacts API calls is currently not captured in the API console.  Which version of Contact API you are using?  V3?

Comment: Thanks Emily for your answer. We are using Contact API V3.